# Exporting CSV data from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, csv

I'm working to export CSV data from Rails. I'm following the tutorial here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel?view=asciicast

In my controller I have:

```
  def show
    # @company is being provided correctly.
    @groups = @company.groups
    render text: @groups.to_csv
  end
```

In my group.rb model:

```
  def self.to_csv
    Rails.logger.info "Hello World"
    CSV.generate do |csv|
      csv << column_names
      all.each do |product|
        csv << product.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
      end
    end
  end
```

The issue is the browser is outputting just the following:

```
#,#,#,#,#,#,#,#,#,#,#,#,#,#,#,#,#,#,#,#,#,#,#
```

The model method appears to be being ignored, even after a Rails restart. What's wrong here?

Comment: also, the model Rails.logger.info is not being logged in the development log file..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `to_csv` is a class method. Meaning its meant to be called like `Group.to_csv`. You might want to change the method signature to something like `Group.to_csv(groups)` instead.

```
 def self.to_csv(groups)
    Rails.logger.info "Hello World"
    CSV.generate do |csv|
      csv << column_names
      groups.each do |product|
        csv << product.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
      end
    end
  end
```

Then in `show`

```
  def show
    # @company is being provided correctly.
    @groups = @company.groups
    render text: Group.to_csv(@groups)
  end
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using class methods on associations.  Rails scopes it for you.   http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html

Comment: how to set bg color

Answer (score 0):

I also met this problem, which was already solved by this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17311372/3458781

Shortly, you have to restart your server. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

A quick version for rails console that is not for prod but just to have access to the data in excel:

first do :

```
print TableName.first.attributes.map{|a,v| a}.join(",")
```

second do :

```
TableName.all.each{|t| print t.attributes.map{|a,v| a}.join(",") + "\n"}; nil
```

copy the result of this two call in a csv file